# QR Code application. Static URL somewhat resistant to spiders?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, dns, qr-code

I am implementing an application to create QR Codes that will be printed in paper media. The app is in Perl and I am successfully generating codes. (using [GD::Barcode::QRCode](http://search.cpan.org/~kwitknr/GD-Barcode-1.15/Barcode/QRcode.pm) btw. Lead pipe cinch..)

The QR Code will contain a static URL. The target scanner will be any QR Code reader on a mobile device. The 'server' is just any web server. My app generates the codes that contain a link to a well known type file (either vCard or vCalendar) that are at variable directories on the server: `http://www.server.com/dir[XYZ]` for example.

Since the QR Code is to be printed, the URL needs to be static.

I know about `X-Robots-Tag: no index` and placing a robot.txt file. While this may deter Google, I am not sure that other spiders respect these tags. Spammer's spiders I can't image do.

**Background:**

This app is to allow printed materials to link to dynamic elements on the web. Most QR Readers (Android, i-nigma, QRReader, etc) will correctly deal with a vCard or vCalendar download. While I can embed the data of the vCard or vCalendar into the QR Code directly, it would be better to have the file on a web server with a URL to that file in the QR Code. While the files does not need to be *secure*, I'd rather they not be cheese for spammers.

I know that if someone typed `http://www.myurl.com/random_string` that the data element there could be downloaded. This is not a concern. I do not want a user confirmation or authentication (unless that is the client's behavior.) Just the file in the directory to be downloaded to the web client when the URL is visited and dealt with if the client knows how to deal with it.

**Question**

If I have `http://www.myserver.com/randomXYZ` with no other links to that URL on the internet, how does a spider find that? Is there some Javascript that I could have in a static URL to do this? Is there a way (that I currently do not see) that a static URL can be somewhat resistant to spiders and robots?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with certainty that this will guarantee that your file(s) will be impervious of spiders but I'd recommend looking at the following site which outlines how directory permissions work.

http://ag.arizona.edu/ecat/web/permissions.html

Directory permissions can be restricted so that access to files must be may via server side requests, for example (php) include, require.

As with any website of course, if someone wants something from your website and puts enough time into it they will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed basic authentication into the link:

http://username:password@www.foo.com